# É possível selecionar todos os elementos com uma determinada classe apenas com CSS?

Tags: css, css3

Estava dando uma olhada nos seletores, e não encontrei uma forma de selecionar todos os elementos que tenham uma determinada classe. Tentei por exemplo:

```
select[form-control] {


}
```

Tentando pegar todos os `selects` com a classe `.form-control` do [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap), mas não deu certo. É possível? Como?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagino que é a isso que se refere:

```
 select.form-control{
    /* seu style */
 }
```

O seletor de classes do css é o ponto `.`

O elemento especificado anteriormente é opcional, poderia ser apenas `.form-control`